# How to solve jpeg2000, jp2. crash & errors on arcgis 9.3.1 windows 7 64-bit

Tags: raster, arcmap, arcgis-9.3

I have several problems at work. One is that jpeg2000 crashes ArcMap but mostly ArcCatalog when trying to read them. This is only occurs on machines with Windows 7 64-bit (we don't have Windows 7 32-bit).

What can cause this? I have deleted templates, re-installed, everything in my power. But there is obviously some compatibility issue, because it works great on Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

There's either a bug in Arc* jpeg2000 driver or your file is corrupt (or a small part of it). I suggest you export the file to another format and reimport it to jpeg2000 to see if it cleans the file. If it's not the case, I fear you will need to change the format to something or use another software (I suggest you look at [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/)).

To convert your file to some other format, you can use anything you want. [GDAL](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries#Windows) is a great tool for that, but only has a command-line interface. Look at [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) documentation for the details, but it will look like that:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff myfile.jp2 myfile.tif
gdal_translate -of JPEG2000 myfile.tif output.jp2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an issue with your image files, in the way they are created. Are you obliged to use jpeg2000? One workaround would be to use good old jpeg or any other common format. Try to convert your images using any image editor (e.g. [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)) or command line tools (like [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)) and see if that helps. For the latter the command would be

```
convert image.jp2 image.jpg
```

If that helps (Arc* does not crash anymore), create your images as .jpg in the first place. Otherwise an exemplary image linked in your question would be helpful.

Comment: problem is; I want it to be as small as jpeg2000 we are not the creator of these jpeg2000, is ecw same compression as jpeg2000? and it works great on arcgis 10.1 and 9.3.1 on xp, not win7

Comment: If you don't want to drop jpeg2000 (the file size compared to jpeg should not be that much smaller), I guess you have to follow Julien-Samuel's answer. Most probably there is a driver related issue or the files are corrupted.